# mysql slave parallel workers from lower version master

Tags: mysql, database, replication, percona

Is there any specific reason for not able to use slave parallel workers while working with lower version of master which not supports parallel workers and higher version of slave which supports parallel workers.
Here i am trying MASTER ( 5.5.28 ) and slave (5.6.19)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this presentation [MySQL Replication High Performance: Multi-Threaded Slaves and 
Group Commit](http://www.mysql.com/news-and-events/events/innovation-day/slides/MySQL_Innovation_Day_Replication_High_Performance.pdf)

It is stated with respect to the multi threaded replica (MTS):

> - Row Based Replication is supported even if replicating from a Master without MTS knowledge (e.g., from a 5.5 MySQL master).
> - Statement Based Replication requires a 5.6 master.

---

Re questions from @vidyadhar:

I don't know if replica performance will be worse if the master is 5.5. I haven't tried that. I don't mean to sound flippant, but if performance is so important to you, why wouldn't you upgrade to 5.6?

Regarding statement based replication and multi-threaded replica, I have not tested that combination. But I have not read any requirement to use row based binlog format for MTS. I assume it would work fine, because the MTS delegates events to replica worker threads based on the database, and every event in the binlog identifies the default database for the event, whether the event is in row based or statement based format.

Comment: I have read in one blog that if master is 5.5 and slave is 5.6 with parallel workers enabled ( of course row based replication ) will degrade slave performance a lot. Is it true ?

Comment: I am very exited to know, What if i have used mixed mode with slave parallel workers and most queries are row based and suddenly one is recorded as statement ?